# Primes satisfying certain conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was studying non-abelian groups of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes such that $q$ divides $p - 1$. I compute two quantities $A$ and $B$ for this group which are given by

$A = (p -1)(q - 1) + \sqrt{(p -1)^2(q - 1)^2 + 4p(p -1)(q - 1)}$

and

$B = \frac{2p^2(p -1)(q - 1) + 2p(q - 1)^2}{pq - 1}$.

We observe that $A < B$ if $q^2 < p + q + 1$. But the condition $q^2 < p + q + 1$ is not true in general. There are many pairs of primes $p, q$ such that $q$ divides $p - 1$ satisfying as well as not satisfying  $q^2 < p + q + 1$. For example, (a) $p = 43, q = 7$; (b) $p = 53, q = 13$; (c) $p = 67, q = 11$; (d) $p = 89, q = 11$ are examples of primes satisfying $q\mid p - 1$ but not $q^2 < p + q + 1$. Examples of pair of primes satisfying $q\mid p - 1$ and  $q^2 < p + q + 1$ are easy to find. Now, I have the following questions:

1. How to find the pairs of primes $p, q$ such that  $q\mid p - 1$ and  $q^2 < p + q + 1$. Is there any characterization of such primes?
2. How to find the pairs of primes $p, q$ such that  $q\mid p - 1$ and  $q^2 > p + q + 1$. Is there any characterization of such primes?

Comment: $p=2kq+1$; $q^2<2kq+1+q+1=(2k+1)q+2$